# puppeteer waits for first element to load

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to check the first element class to load in my page to execute my code. For example, my page can have 3 different states, it can have a popup with class `.a` or it can have a page with class `.b` or a page with class `.c`. So I would like to wait one of them to load and get which one loaded first. I tried to do it with `Promise.race`. My code:

```
await page.goto('myurl', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 30000 }).then(async () => {
await Promise.race([
     page.waitForSelector('.a'),
     page.waitForSelector('.b'),
     page.waitForSelector('.c'),
   ], {timeout: 60000 })
   console.log('done loading one of the 3 elements')
}).catch(e => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

But after that, I get en error that for example class `.b` could not load in 60000ms. Isnt it supposed to work? `Promise.race` is still running after one of them executed. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a place in the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) where `Promise.race()` takes a `{timeout: ...}` argument.

If you want to set a timeout, I would do it in the `page.waitForSelector` in Puppeteer.

```
    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53624870/puppeteer-waits-for-first-element-to-load', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 30000 })
        .then(async () => {
            let elementHandle = await Promise.race([
                page.waitForSelector('.post-text', {timeout: 60000}),
                page.waitForSelector('.should-fail', {timeout: 60000}),
                page.waitForSelector('.should-fail-2', {timeout: 60000}),
            ]);

            console.log(elementHandle != null);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
```

And also, but that would be my personnal way of writing it, I would await everything and not mix await/then, like so :

```
    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53624870/puppeteer-waits-for-first-element-to-load', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 30000 })
        .catch(e => console.error(e));

    let elementHandle = await Promise.race([
        page.waitForSelector('.post-text', {timeout: 60000}),
        page.waitForSelector('.should-fail', {timeout: 60000}),
        page.waitForSelector('.should-fail-2', {timeout: 60000})
    ]);

    console.log(elementHandle != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`{ visible: true}` is something to be considered . like :

```
const elementHandle = await Promise.race([
            this.page.waitForSelector(selector_1, { timeout: 4000, visible: true })
            .catch(),
            this.page.waitForSelector(selector_2, { timeout: 4000, visible: true })
            .catch(),
        ]);
```