# Waiting for selector and Navigating at same time

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Is it possible to `wait for a selector` **and continue** with the `navigation` of the page `at the same time`?

Here is an example in a basic pseudo-code

```
wait for selector (`.modal.error`) //search and wait for this selector until appears caused by an user interaction

browser go to page (`https://my-test-page.com/page1.html`)

browser wait for selector (`#user`) //this selector is found

browser wait for selector (`#password`) //this selector is found

browser wait for selector (`#login`) //this selector is found

//(`.modal.error`) was found because password was entered incorrectly by user-input

//do something because selector (`.modal.error`) was found

browser close();
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Have you tried storing the wait for selector in a variable name (it'll be a `Promise`) and then `await`ing it later, while doing your other operations in the meantime? (just a guess)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply

It seems to me that what you are referring to is a sequential instruction?

If I have to wait but I did not know when the selector would appear, it is also possible that it never appears, but I could not wait infinitely :(

Will you have a more accurate example to represent your idea? :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Puppeter, but I know Promises, you might be able to use `Promise.race` with a Promise that rejects after 60 seconds (or however long you want to wait for the element to appear)

Comment: CertainPerformance  Thank you very much for all your supportI will start to investigate the solution you propose and I hope you can review here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53624870/puppeteer-waits-for-first-element-to-load So if you have any other suggestion, we'll be happy to review it